# Multidimentional array Index out of range. C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a 2d array which is 5 across 8 down. It works when I don't enter a value. But as soon as I enter a value it has the out of range error.

This is part of a quiz.

```
int score = 0;
string question;
Console.WriteLine("You will be asked a random question from one of the topics at a random difficulty");

for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(2);
    int y = random.Next(7);
    Console.WriteLine(Questions[x, y]);
    question = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (question == (Answers[x, y]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct");
        score++;
    }
}
static string[,] Answers =
{
    { "A", "B", "B", "A", "A" },
    { "A", "A", "B", "A", "A" },
    { "A", "B", "A", "B", "A" }
};

static string[,] Questions =
{
    { "1.Name the organelles where protiens are synthesised? A.Ribosome or B.Mitchodria: ",
        "2.What enzyme breaks down carbohydrases? A.Lipids or B.Carbohydrases: ",
        "3.What is meant by the definition of comunicable disease? A.The disease can talk or B.A disease that can be transmitted from person to person: ",
        "4.Define photosynthesis? A.the process where plants sunlight to synthesize nutrients from carbon dioxide and water or B.Where plants take pictures: ",
        "5.What part of your body never stops growing? A.Ears or B.Hands: " },
    { "1.Name the organelles where protiens are synthesised? A.Ribosome or B.Mitchodria or C.Nucleaus: ",
        "2.What enzyme breaks down carbohydrases? A.Lipids or B.Carbohydrases or C.Protease: ",
        "3.What is meant by the definition of comunicable disease? A.The disease can talk or B.A disease that can be transmitted from person to person or C.A disease that can\"t be transmitted from person to person: ",
        "4.Define photosynthesis? A.the process where plants sunlight to synthesize nutrients from carbon dioxide and water or B.Where plants take pictures or C.Where plants use sunlight and oxygen to synthesize nutrients?: ",
        "5.What part of your body never stops growing? A.Ears or B.Hands or C.Feet: " },
    { "1.Name the organelles where protiens are synthesised? A.Ribosome or B.Mitchodria or C.Nucleaus or D.Vacuole: ",
        "2.What enzyme breaks down carbohydrases? A.Lipids or B.Carbohydrases or C.Protease or D.Amylase: ",
        "3.What is meant by the definition of comunicable disease? A.The disease can talk or B.A disease that can be transmitted from person to person or C.A disease that can\"t be transmitted from person to person or D.A communist disease: ",
        "4.Define photosynthesis? A.the process where plants sunlight to synthesize nutrients from carbon dioxide and water or B.Where plants take pictures or C.Where plants use sunlight and oxygen to synthesize nutrients or D.Where plants user CO2 and glucose to produce Oxygen: ",
        "5.What part of your body never stops growing? A.Ears or B.Hands or C.Feet D.Body: "},
    { "1.What is largest planet in our solar system? A.Jupiter or B.Saturn: ",
        "2.Which of the following planets does not have rings? A.Mars or B.Saturn: ",
        "3.How long does it take the Earth to complete a full orbit around the Sun? A.2 years or B.1 year: ",
        "4.Whats the biggest star in our solar system? A.The sun or B.The moon: ",
        "5.What is the hottest planet in our solar system? A.Mercury or B.Venus: "},
    { "1.What is largest planet in our solar system? A.Jupiter or B.Saturn or C.Neptune: ",
        "2.Which of the following planets does not have rings? A.Mars or B.Saturn or C.Juipter: ",
        "3.How long does it take the Earth to complete a full orbit around the Sun? A.2 years or B.1 year or C.10 years: ",
        "4.Whats the biggest star in our solar system? A.The sun or B.The moon or C.The Earth: ",
        "5.What is the hottest planet in our solar system? A.Mercury or B.Venus or C.Mars: "},
    { "1.What is largest planet in our solar system? A.Jupiter or B.Saturn or C.Neptune or D.Uranus: ",
        "2.Which of the following planets does not have rings? A.Mars or B.Saturn or C.Jupiter or D.Uranus: ",
        "3.How long does it take the Earth to complete a full orbit around the Sun? A.2 years or B.1 year or C.10 years or D.100 years: ",
        "4.Whats the biggest star in our solar system? A.The sun or B.The moon or C.The Earth or D.None of these: ",
        "5.What is the hottest planet in our solar system? A.Mercury or B.Venus or C.Mars or D.Pluto: "},
    { "1.Hexadecimal means? A.Base 16 or B.Base 8: ",
        "2.How many bits are in a byte? A.6 or B.8: ",
        "3.How many MB in a Gigga byte A.1024MB or B.2028MB: ",
        "4.Define open source software A.It\"s an open bottle of ketchup or B.It\"s a free program: ",
        "5.Which of these is an example of secondry? A.SSD or B.Cache: "},
    { "1.Hexadecimal means? A.Base 16 or B.Base 8 or C.base 10: ",
        "2.How many bits are in a byte? A.6 or B.8 or C.16: ",
        "3.How many MB in a Gigga byte A.1024MB or B.2028MB or C.1024kb: ",
        "4.Define open source software A.It\"s an open bottle of ketchup or B.It\"s a free program OR C.It\"s a paid subscription: ",
        "5.Which of these is an example of secondry? A.SSD or B.Cache or C.RAM: "},
    { "1.Hexadecimal means? A.Base 16 or B.Base 8 or C.base 10 or D.Base 2: ",
        "2.How many bits are in a byte? A.6 or B.8 or C.16 or D.4: ",
        "3.How many MB in a Gigga byte A.1024MB or B.2028MB or C.1024kb or D.3072: ",
        "4.Define open source software A.It\"s an open bottle of ketchup or B.It\"s a free program OR C.It\"s a paid subscription or D.None of these: ",
        "5.Which of these is an example of secondry? A.SSD or B.Cache or C.RAM or D.ROM: "}
};
```

Comment: The dimensions of the answers don't seem to match the questions... The questions are 5 across and 9 down, but the answers are 5 across and 3 down?

Comment: your answers array is 3*5, but you random 3*8 -> out of range.

Comment: and Mr Sweeper is right also!

Comment: @MarioWu - The OP's random is `2*7`, not `3*8` as you're suggesting.

Comment: @Enigmativity ah, right, can't reach Max value, I can't remember that, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are causing you grief:

```
int x = random.Next(2);
int y = random.Next(7);
```

`x` can only have a value of either `0` or `1` and `y` can have a value from `0` to `6`.

Since your arrays only have `5` elements in the second dimension you're getting your error when `y == 5` or `y == 6`.

---

Here's something for you to play with:

```
    var question = Questions[random.Next(Questions.Length)];
    
    var options =
        question
            .Answers
            .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
            .Select((a, n) => new { a, o = (char)(n + 'A') })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.o, x => x.a);

    Console.WriteLine(question.Question);
    foreach (var option in options.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{option.Key}: {option.Value}");
    }

    var answer = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().First();
    
    if (options[answer] == question.Answers[0])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct");
        score++;
    }


static (string Question, string[] Answers)[] Questions = new (string Question, string[] Answers)[]
{
    ("Name the organelles where protiens are synthesised?", new [] { "Lipids", "Carbohydrases" }),
    ("What enzyme breaks down carbohydrases?", new [] { "Carbohydrases", "Lipids" }),
    ("What is meant by the definition of comunicable disease?", new [] { "A disease that can be transmitted from person to person.", "The disease can talk." }),
    ("Define photosynthesis?", new [] { "the process where plants sunlight to synthesize nutrients from carbon dioxide and water.", "Where plants take pictures." }),
    ("What part of your body never stops growing?", new [] { "Ears", "Hands" }),
};
```

The questions and answers are packed together and the first answer is always correct (they get shuffled up when being asked).